# Java Many to Many Relation Duplicate Entry Exception

Tags: java, many-to-many, relational-database, many-to-one, duplicates

I have 3 tables:

- Person:  id, name
- Property: id, description
- Person_x_Properties:  id_person, id_property

On java I have a code like this example:

EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

person.setPropertyList(propertyList);
property.setPersonList(personList);

```
for (...) {
    //
    //  <-no problem with these lines there are only numeric operations
    //
    em.merge(property);
}

em.merge(person);
```

Then i get the message (duplicate entry at person_x_properties [xxx, yyy]).

I have been searching for solutions and i have 1 possible:

- assign the list only in one of them.

It works but i dont like it because i need the information in the two objects for the future.

Anyone can give me an orientation please?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry on the for bucle, it is bad tabulated.  At the end of the bucle there is a merge sentence.  Thanks again!!